# Issues with Segmentation in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am new to GEE and coding in general and I am trying to conduct segmentation on an image. I am building on an existing code from another related project however, I am getting the error:

> clusters: Layer error: Image.select: Pattern 'B2_median' did not match
> any bands.

I can't seem to figure it out and I am mirroring what I have seen in another script so not sure what is going on. The bottom of the script (the part dealing with segmentation) is where I am experiencing issues.

```
*//1 Mask Clouds
function maskS2clouds(sentColl) {
var qa = sentColl.select('QA60');
  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;
  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));
  return sentColl.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
}
//2. Define Sentinel-2 Image Collection
var sentColl = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED')
                  .filterDate('2019-01-01', '2023-01-01')
                 .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(06, 8, 'month')) 
                  .filterMetadata ('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 'less_than', 10)
                  .filterBounds(AOI)
                  //.select(['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B8'])
                  .map(maskS2clouds);
                 
print(sentColl);
//4. Compute the median in each band and each pixel and then select RGBI bands. Band names are B2_Median, B3_Median etc.
 var imgMed = sentColl.reduce(ee.Reducer.median())
.select('B2_median', 'B3_median', 'B4_median', 'B8_median');
print(imgMed)
 //5. Output image. Add it to map.
var VisualizeP = {
bands:['B2_median', 'B3_median', 'B4_median'],
min:0.012,
max:0.145,
gamma:1.30,
};
//Map.addLayer(imgMed,VisualizeP);
Map.centerObject(AOI,10);
//Clip image
var NSSent = imgMed.clip(AOI)
Map.addLayer(NSSent,VisualizeP, '2019_2023NSSS');
//Export Sentinel-2 Mosaic
Export.image.toDrive({
  image:NSSent,
  description: '2019_2023NSSS',
  scale: 10,
  region: AOI,
  maxPixels:16792443500
})
print(NSSent)
//Calculate NDVI using the Median  Image
var ndvi = NSSent.normalizedDifference(['B8_median', 'B4_median']).rename('NDVI');
print(ndvi)
//Display NDVI
Map.addLayer(ndvi, {min:-1, max:1, palette: ['blue', 'yellow', 'green']}, 'NDVI');
//Export NDVI to drive
Export.image.toDrive({
  image:ndvi,
  description: '2019_2023NDVI',
  scale: 10,
  region: AOI,
  maxPixels: 16792443500
})
//Calculate NDWI
var ndwi = NSSent.normalizedDifference(['B3_median','B8_median'])
//Display NDWI
Map.addLayer(ndwi, {min:-1, max:1, palette: ['yellow', 'green', 'blue']}, 'NDWI');
//Export NDWI to drive
Export.image.toDrive({
  image:ndwi,
  description: '2019_2023NDWI',
  scale: 10,
  region: AOI,
  maxPixels: 16792443500
});
//Calculate Anthocyanin Relfective Index (ARI) #1
var ari = imgMed.expression(('(B8/B2) - (B8/B3)'), {
    'B8': imgMed.select(['B8_median']),
    'B3': imgMed.select(['B3_median']), 
    'B2':imgMed.select(['B2_median']),
   }).rename('ARI')
//Display ARI #1 on GEE
Map.addLayer(ari, {min:-1, max:1, palette: ['White', 'pink', 'purple']}, 'ARI');
//Export ARI #1 to drive
Export.image.toDrive({
  image:ari,
  description: '2019_2023ARI',
  scale: 10,
  region: AOI,
  maxPixels: 16792443500
});
//Calculate Anthocyanin Relfective Index (ARI) #2 - 
 var ari2 = function(img){
 return img.expression('(1/B3) - (1/B5)', {
    'B3': img.select(['B3']), 
    'B5':img.select(['B5']),
   }).rename('ARI2');
}
var ari2Median = ari2(sentColl.median()).select('ARI2')
//Clip image
var ari2Median = ari2Median.clip(AOI)
//Display ARI # 2 on GEE
Map.addLayer(ari2Median, { palette: ['White', 'pink', 'green'],}, 'ARI2');
Export.image.toDrive({
  image:ari2Median,
 description: '2019_2023ARI2',
  scale: 10,
  region: AOI,
  maxPixels: 16792443500
});
//--normalized Anthocyanin Reflectance Index, Bayle et al (2019)
var addNARI = function(image) {
  return image.addBands(image.expression(
   '((1/B3) - (1/B5))/((1/B3) + (1/B5))', {
    'B5': image.select(['B5']),
    'B3': image.select(['B3']), 
   }).rename('NARI'));
}
var ari3Median = addNARI(sentColl.median()).select('NARI')
//Clip image
var ari3Median = ari3Median.clip(AOI)
//Display ARI # 2 on GEE
Map.addLayer(ari3Median, { palette: ['White', 'pink', 'green'],}, 'NARI');
Export.image.toDrive({
  image:ari3Median,
 description: '2019_2023NARI',
  scale: 10,
  region: AOI,
  maxPixels: 16792443500
});
//Calculate REIP
var reip = function(img){
  return img.expression('700 + 40*((B4+B7)/2 - B5)/(B6 - B5)', {
    'B4': img.select(['B4']),
    'B7': img.select(['B7']), 
    'B6': img.select(['B6']),
    'B5': img.select(['B5']),
   }).rename('REIP');
}
var reipMedian = reip(sentColl.median()).select('REIP');
//Clip Image
var reipMedian2 = reipMedian.clip(AOI)
   //Display REIP on GEE
Map.addLayer(reipMedian2, { palette: ['White', 'orange', 'green'], min: 700, max: 750}, 'REIP');
   //Export REIP to drive
Export.image.toDrive({
  image:reipMedian2,
  description: '2019_2023REIP',
  scale: 10,
  region: AOI,
  maxPixels: 16792443500
});
//Set Sentinel-2 4 band mosaic for segmentation
//Set seeds for segmentation and apply softening
var seeds = ee.Algorithms.Image.Segmentation.seedGrid(36, 'hex');
var kernel = ee.Kernel.gaussian(3);
//Select 10 m bands
var bands10m = ['B2_median','B3_median','B4_median','B8_median'];
var img10m = imgMed.select(bands10m);
// Apply light smoothing to bands
var img10mSmoo = img10m.convolve(kernel);
//Run SNIC algorithm 
//// Parameters determined by experimentation
//// Ideal clusters follow the shape of natural features
//// but are not too long and thin because features which cross tiles
//// may cause data gaps in the output
//// Clusters were assessed with map display zoomed in to a 5 m scale
//// 5m was chosen as the scale at which the clusters best matched the target features
//// This is not to be confused with input image resolutions which vary from 10-30 m pixel size
var snic = ee.Algorithms.Image.Segmentation.SNIC({
  image: img10mSmoo,
  compactness: 0.4, 
  connectivity: 4,
  neighborhoodSize: 64,
  seeds: seeds
}).select(['B2_median', 'B3_median', 'B4_median', 'B8_median', 'clusters']);
var clusters = snic.select(['clusters']);
//Optional: Display clusters generated from SNIC
// Zoom in to scale of 5 m (Check with Inspector)
Map.addLayer(clusters.randomVisualizer(), null, 'clusters', false);
// add clusters to image
var img = imgMed.addBands(clusters.rename('clusters'));*
```

Answer (score 0):

The output bandnames of SNIC come up with OriginalBandName_mean. So you have to change the bandname in your script and here is the modified version of your script tested for random AOI.
[enter link description here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/96b460a598f300fb3c69dd5e741ef57e)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please include code as formatted text rather than only as a link.